# Vue3//Vuex - how do I add the store only after it has initialized its modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex-modules

I ran into a problem earlier where mapState() does not create (simple value retrieving) getters automatically for store modules.  Or maybe it was a timing issue.  The docs say this:

> "When a component needs to make use of multiple store state properties
> or getters, declaring all these computed properties can get repetitive
> and verbose. To deal with this we can make use of **the mapState helper**
> which **generates computed getter functions for us**, saving us some
> keystrokes:"
>
> https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html

Using mapState() in a component computed property worked great - until I moved some of that state into a module, at which point it quit working.  Adding a getter to pull the state property did work but I dislike the code duplication when retrieving simple, not computed, values.  If it was due to timing, is there a store.ready(app.use(store)) function somewhere?

```js
// store.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import products from './products.js'
import cart from './cart.js'

const store = createStore({
   modules:{
      products,
      cart
   },
   state() {
      return {
         isLoggedIn: false,
      }
   },
   mutations: {
      login(state) {
         state.isLoggedIn = true;
      },
      logout(state) {
         state.isLoggedIn = false;
      },
   },
})

export default store;
```

```js
// products.js

export default {
   state() {
      return {
         products: [
            {
               id: 'p1',
               image:
                  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Books_HD_%288314929977%29.jpg/640px-Books_HD_%288314929977%29.jpg',
               title: 'Book Collection',
               description:
                  'A collection of must-read books. All-time classics included!',
               price: 99.99,
            },
         ],
      }
   },
   getters:{
      products(state){
         return state.products;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<!-- productList.vue -->

<template>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <product-item
        v-for="prod in products"
        :key="prod.id"
        :id="prod.id"
        :title="prod.title"
        :image="prod.image"
        :description="prod.description"
        :price="prod.price"
      ></product-item>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import ProductItem from '../components/products/ProductItem.vue';
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
//import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    ProductItem,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([       //This does not work
      'products'
    ])
    // ...mapGetters([    This does
    //   'products'
    // ])
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.products)
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: You can use `mapState` with modules. Please update the question to show the code that uses it with modules.

Comment: I added some code.  I should mention that I see this.products in the console, so it's there somehow.  But v-for doesn't pick it up when I use mapState.  It does pick it up when I switch to mapGetters.  And it was working before I switched to modules.

Comment: Are your modules namespaced? They aren't in your question but that's not very typical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module state is *always* namespaced. For example, your `products` state in the `products` module is only available under

```js
//          module  state
store.state.products.products
```

To use `mapState` with a module, you can use either of these options

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    products: state => state.products.products
  }),
  ...mapState("products", {
    products: state.products
  })
  ...mapState("products", [
    "products"
  ])
}
```

Each of these will map the `products` state from the `products` module to `this.products` in your component.

---

Your *getters* work because your modules are not namespaced and therefore...

> By default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still registered under the **global namespace**

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Thank you.  Given this explanation and the code above, why do I see the product struct in the console when using mapState() (mounted())?  That's what was throwing me - this.products is there, but v-for doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @Daemach sorry, I'm not following you there. If you need something clarified, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64250964/edit) so you can add some proper code examples

Comment: In the code sample above I am using mapState() and doing .mounted() { console.log(this.products) }.  I can see the product array in the console, so why doesn't v-for see it?

Comment: @Daemach what exactly do you see in the console? Because your module is also called `products`, it's probably mapping `store.state.products` (the module) to `this.products`. If you see an object with "products" key, eg `{"products": [...]}` then that is the case

Comment: Yes, that's what I see.  Thanks again for the help and explanation.